# Passing data to One Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

Sorry for asking the Repeated question but after checking other question i use their answer They are not working in my code I am new to android

**Here is the class where i want to pass the data**

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>   {


    private int[] mdataset;
    private String[] mplanet;

    Context c;
    public MainAdapter(Context context ,int[] dataset , String[] planet){

        this.c = context;
        this.mplanet = planet;
        this.mdataset = dataset;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position ) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(mdataset[position]);
        holder.textView.setText(mplanet[position]);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {


      //   here is my i want to pass the data position to another fragment** 


                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("position", position);
                bottomActivity fragment = new bottomActivity();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mdataset.length;
    }




    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


           View  v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                   .inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

}
```

**Here is my `Fragment` class Where i want to receive the data**

```
public class bottomActivity extends Fragment
 {

    TextView textView;
    int pos;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);

        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_textView);

        textView.setText(pos+"");
        return  view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


//  here is that code where the data should received 

        Bundle bundle = bottomActivity.this.getArguments();

        if (bundle != null) 
        {

            pos = bundle.getInt("position", 2);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you have not added or replaced fragment in onclick,you are just binding the bundle to fragment

Comment: can you explain more in details i do not have much knowleage in that

Comment: tell me what should i do

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);

        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
        // get data from the bundle you sent
        int position=getArguments().getInt("position");

        textView.setText(position+"");
        return  view;
    }
```

In your onCreatView of fragment do like this

Comment: post the code where you are committig the fragment and post the code where you are creating view for the fragment, with that i think i'll better understand what your problem is, actually

Comment: you mean xml file

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have static newInstance method in fragment, and send all data you need like parametars. Next step is onCreate method in fragment get all data you passed.

e.g

Activity

```
YourFragment fragment = YourFragment.newInstance(10, 4);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(id, fragment).commit();
```

Fragment

```
int data1, data2;
 public static YourFragment newInstance(int data1, int data2) {
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("data1", data1);
    args.putInt("data2", data2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    data1 = getArguments().getInt("data1", 0);
    data2 = getArguments().getInt("data2", 0);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I think you need this case, sending data before fragment is created.

Cheers :)

Comment: the problem is getFragmentManager is showing error if i use that its cannot resolve it

Comment: Did you try with  getSupportFragmentManager() ?

Comment: can i send a link of my code can you figure out where is the problem it takes my whole  day to solve that problem still not solve it  Can you try to solve please

Comment: cannot resolve method getFragmentManager() or getFragmentSupportManager ()

Comment: Now I see... You try to start Fragment from RecyclerAdapter and that is not good. Because getSupport/getFragmentManager() exists in Activity. Solution for this is interface with method startFragment(), and you need to implement that method where you create Adapter (in Activity or Fragment). In that implementation you put code for starting fragment.

Comment: i found a link in android developer but i new to android https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html   .........can you explain me what is this link try i use in my code

Comment: i still not get fully how to use startFragment() and put it my code i am ameture at android programming

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `onClick` method in Adapter class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);           
    bottomActivity fragment = new bottomActivity ();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, fragment).commit();
   }
```

where CONTENT_VIEW_ID is the container which should be defined in your activity class

then in `bottomActivity` fragment class in `onCreateView`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container,         false);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) 
        {
            pos = bundle.getInt("position", 2);
        }
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
        textView.setText(pos+"");
        return  view;
    }
```

Comment: you means i have to  implements View.OnClickListener  and implement that onClick method

Comment: getFragmentManager is in error mark its saying that "cannot resolve it "